# Javascrips youtube subtitles doesn't work on mobile fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, youtube

Please help!!!

i have used this code:
http://siloor.com/youtube.external.subtitle/examples/srt

to make an SRT subtitles to youtube video.
but the subtitles doesn't work on full screen on mobile!! (especially iphone)

please help!!!!

this is the video:
http://www.simplepsy.co.il/corner-of-surprises/dad-handle-his-daughters-walmart-tantrum/

this is the code i used- in this code i wanted to disable the FULL SCREEN button because of the problem.

```
<iframe id="video" width="100%" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xBi9jaOFcRU?playsinline=1" frameborder="0" fs="0"></iframe>
<script src="http://www.simplepsy.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/youtube.external.subtitle.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.simplepsy.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/subtitles.parser.js"></script>
<script>
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        var subtitles = parser.fromSrt(httpRequest.responseText, true);

        for (var i in subtitles) {
            subtitles[i] = {
                start : subtitles[i].startTime / 1000,
                end   : subtitles[i].endTime / 1000,
                text  : subtitles[i].text
            };
        }

        var youtubeExternalSubtitle = new YoutubeExternalSubtitle.Subtitle(document.getElementById('video'), subtitles);
    }
};

httpRequest.open('GET', 'http://www.simplepsy.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/walmartsubt.srt', true);
httpRequest.send(null);
</script>
```

Comment: Please add code that you have already tried

Comment: i did :) please help

Comment: ??/?????????????????